# session variable from different database with different hosting

Tags: php, database, session, variables

I am now trying to build a wp website. 
I will add a php page that will interact with a different database. 
According to GODADDY, I cannot have another database in the same hosting(server). 
If I don't have the databases in the same servers, I will not be able to bring session variables.
Is this fact true?

Should I just use cookies to pass variables such as userID/customerID?

Answer (score 0):

if we are get data from multiple database and database hosted on multiple server we can manage session in database it's easy to handle this situation.
session table must be federated  engine in MySQL

Comment: thanks for the reply! to which database I have to add the session table? to both? or the one that would be receiving the session variable?

Comment: Primary database you have add session table but table engine must be federated

Comment: read this link it will be help for you =>  [link](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)